# How can Cobb use Mal's totem for a reality check

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

How can Cobb use Mal's totem for a reality check?

Isn't this defeating the whole idea of totems.

That totem belongs to Mal so how can Cobb use that to check for reality. Wouldn't that give inaccurate result??

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/why-does-cobb-use-the-spinning-top/) and [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/is-it-actually-possible-to-transfer-a-totem).

Comment: Agree on the duplicate point, particularly the second one.